# Location Listener onLocationChange () method not working

Tags: java, android, location, locationlistener

**My Android Phone model # is Sony Z3 Compact Japanese (SO-O2G)
Google Maps and all other apps related to location Works fine on my device
But i want to develop my own location-based application and on First step of developing my code is not working.. I don't know what is the problem in my Code. onLocationChange () method not triggered.. Even not finding my current location**

**Manifest Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testingpurpose">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.testingpurpose;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private double distanceIntoMeters;
    private final String PERMISSION_ONE = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private final String PERMISSION_TWO = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,PERMISSION_ONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,PERMISSION_TWO ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{PERMISSION_ONE, PERMISSION_TWO}, 0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if ( locationManager != null ){

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,PERMISSION_ONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,PERMISSION_TWO ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
            }
        }

        else{

            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        periodicallyCheck();
    }

    void periodicallyCheck(){

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String format = String.format("%.2f %s",distanceIntoMeters,"meters");
                tv.setText(format);
                handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if ( lastLocation == null ){

                lastLocation = location;
            }

            Log.i("Location Updates: ",">>> Lat "+location.getLatitude()+" , >>> Long "+location.getLongitude());

            distanceIntoMeters = distanceIntoMeters + location.distanceTo(lastLocation);
            lastLocation = location;

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (locationManager != null && listener != null){

            locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

**activityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I believe it's better to use [Google Location API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java) rather than LocationManager that you are using right now